# Installed Cuda 8 and it seems to be missing npp.lib

Tags: c++, cuda

I have some old code that I inherited and I am trying to upgrade it to the latest cuda, so I installed Cuda 8 but when compiling it complains about not being able to find npp.lib, I checked the C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\lib\x64 and cant find it, I see a bunch of npp{xxx}.lib where xxx is more text, but nothing that is just npp.lib.  Has this been removed in the latest cuda?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `npp.lib` was replaced by `nppi.lib` and `npps.lib` and `nppc.lib` somewhere around CUDA 6.5 or before. This is referred to in the [CUDA 8 npp documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/pdf/NPP_Library_Image_Arithmetic_And_Logic.pdf), chapter 1:

> Note: Starting with release 6.5, NPP is also provided as a static library (libnppc_static.a, libnppi_static.a,
>   and libnpps_static.a) on Linux, Android, and Mac OSes in addition to being provided as a shared library.
>   The static NPP libraries depend on a common thread abstraction layer library called cuLIBOS (libculibos.a)
>   that is now distributed as part of the toolkit. Consequently, cuLIBOS must be provided to the linker when
>   the static library is being linked against. The libnppi library is becoming quite large so to minimize library
>   loading and CUDA runtime startup times it is recommended to use the static library(s) whenever possible.
>   To improve loading and runtime performance when using dynamic libraries NPP 8.0 now includes the full
>   set of nppi sub-libraries in addition to the full sized nppi library itself. Linking to only the sub-libraries
>   that contain functions that your application uses can significantly improve load time and runtime startup
>   performance. Some nppi functions make calls to other nppi and/or npps functions internally so you may
>   need to link to a few extra libraries depending on what function calls your application makes. The nppi
>   sub-libraries are split into sections corresponding to the way that nppi header files are split. There are also
>   static versions of each of the new sub-libraries. The full sized nppi library will be deprecated in the next
>   CUDA release. This list of sub-libraries is as follows:
>
> nppial arithmetic and logical operation functions in nppi_arithmetic_and_logical_operations.h
>
> nppicc color conversion and sampling functions in nppi_color_conversion.h
>
> nppicom JPEG compression and decompression functions in nppi_compression_functions.h
>
> nppidei data exchange and initialization functions in nppi_data_exchange_and_initialization.h
>
> nppif filtering and computer vision functions in nppi_filter_functions.h
>
> nppig geometry transformation functions found in nppi_geometry_transforms.h
>
> nppim morphological operation functions found in 
>    nppi_morphological_operations.h
>
> nppist statistics and linear transform in nppi_statistics_functions.h and 
>    nppi_linear_transforms.h
>
> nppisu memory support functions in nppi_support_functions.h
>
> nppitc threshold and compare operation functions in 
>    nppi_threshold_and_compare_operations.h

In addition note above that `nppi` is further subdivided.  You'll need to change link specifications.